# Flutter need to build IOS

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

i have catalina os in Macbook pro 2012 and I want to build IOS app on Flutter but it required Monterey OS to run Xcode 13 so does anyone know any alternative way to run ios semulator with flutter without Xcode 13

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your hardware is too old to have the new updates and you will not be able to install the new versions of XCode.
Your best shot is to either change your hardware or to use a service such as https://flutterci.com/ to build your app on their hardware.